# Is it possible to use a spring configuration XML file per jar file with additional info?

Tags: java, spring, plugins, configuration, configuration-files

My main Spring Configuration XML file specifies something like this:

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.application" />`

The components found during this scan can be in one of many jar files on my classpath.  I'd like to be able to have additional spring configuration XML files in each jar file that provide more information about each individual service/component (maybe some properties and whatnot), but I don't want these things to be tightly coupled to my main application's configuration file.

Is there a way to do this, or am I out of luck?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to somehow autodetect the existence of the XML file in the JAR file, based on name and/or location in the JAR file.

I know some things like this can be done with META-INF, but that's far beyond my area of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ideally, I'd like to be able to somehow autodetect the existence of the XML file in the JAR file, based on name and/or location in the JAR file.

Yes, this is pretty straightforward.

In your main Spring context file, add something like this:

```
<import resource="classpath*:config.xml"/>
```

Note the wildcard syntax.  This will scan the root of the classpath looking for any resources called `config.xml`, and will import them into your main context.

So your JARs can each have a `config.xml` in their root directory, and it'll just happen. Those `config.xml` files can, of course, perform their own imports, and so on.

Comment: I knew it had to be ridiculously simple, trying this now!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if any problems would arise if 2 of those config.xml files both imported the same config.xml file out of a 3rd JAR?  i.e. What if 1 config.xml file gets processed twice?

Comment: @Luke: The bean definitions of one would be overriden by the bean definitions from the other. You'd get lots of warnings, but it should still work.  Best avoided, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I also realized that circular references in the config files is really bad!